I created this new blueprint function library and made a simple function named getpointlessmessage but it doesnt pop up when is search for it in BP
he is my code for the header file
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once
#include "UObject/Object.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h"



UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT2_API UMyBlueprintFunctionLibrary : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
{
public:

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable);
    static FString GetPointlessMessage();
protected:

private:
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
};

here is my code for the cpp file
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"

FString UMyBlueprintFunctionLibrary::GetPointlessMessage()
{
    return FString(TEXT("Hi guys"));
}


their are no other errors other  than the regular intelliscence errors
but if you want to see them here are they
enter image description here
I tried to debug and run the code nothing poped up i also made sure i was in devolopment editor mode
so if some one can help me it would be great
what i did was run from visual studio after saving, I opened the blueprint file of the level and searched for pointless and couldnt find any thing i also searched for the whole name getpointlessmessage still found nothing!
enter image description here

Why are you using two Stack Overflow accounts to ask questions? Is this also you?

British Petroleum?

Where are your files in your UE project? Did you compile the sources of the project after modifying them?

yes i compiled my project and everything my files are in the normal place i did not change any files places or anything this is a brand new project with a bit of simple code @DatGeoudon

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Had to remove two things the ; in UFUNCTION
and had to remove TEXT from the cpp file in the return
that fixed everything and it works now!!!!
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once
#include "UObject/Object.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h"



UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT2_API UMyBlueprintFunctionLibrary : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
{
public:

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    static FString GetPointlessMessage();
protected:

private:
    GENERATED_BODY()
};

cpp file
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"

FString UMyBlueprintFunctionLibrary::GetPointlessMessage()
{
    return FString(("Hi guys"));
}


Removing TEXT() didn't fix your issue. It shouldn't be removed as the constructor now has to convert the string to TCHAR at runtime..

no it did fix my issue as because i am returning a string and the in blueprints printing a string it waits for another return which doesnt exist
